# Netflix ZuulProxy returns HTTP error 500 even the microservice is registered in Eureka Service Discovery

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have a microservice what is registered in eureka and I can see in the service discovery. Also I have a Zuul server with the correct eureka server service url.

Zuul application.properties file:

```
spring.application.name=zuul-server
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:https://"eureka-server"/eureka}
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=routes
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=5000
```

Zuul application.yml file:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    unasapi:
      path: /microservice/**
      serviceId: microservice
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
microservice:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: https://microservice.com/
```

My Eureka server application.properties file:

```
server.port:8760

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF

eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=false
eureka.server.renewal-percent-threshold=0.85
```

My Eureka server application.yml file:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 15000
ribbon:
    ReadTimeout: 15000
```

My Microservice application.properties file:

```
server.port=62114
```

And my Microservice application.yml file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: microservice
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://eureka.com/eureka
```

The stacktrace what I've got :

```
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434034+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-09-10 08:38:21.433  WARN 4 --- [nio-7154-exec-6] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434045+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434048+00:00 app[web.1]: com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434050+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:191) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434051+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:166) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434053+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:114) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434055+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434056+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434058+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434059+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434060+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434062+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434063+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434064+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434066+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434067+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434069+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434071+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434072+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434074+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434075+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434077+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434078+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434079+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434080+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434082+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434083+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434085+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434086+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434087+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434089+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434096+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434097+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434098+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434100+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434119+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434120+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434122+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434123+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434124+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434126+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434127+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434128+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434130+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434131+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434133+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434134+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434136+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434137+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434138+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434140+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434141+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434142+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434144+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434145+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434146+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434148+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434149+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434151+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434152+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434159+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:677) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434160+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434162+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434178+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434180+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434181+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434182+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434184+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_222-heroku]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434185+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_222-heroku]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434186+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434188+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222-heroku]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434189+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: ks-supersync-unasapi
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434190+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434192+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434193+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434194+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434196+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434197+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434198+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434200+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434201+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434202+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434204+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434205+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434206+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434208+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434209+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434211+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434212+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434214+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434215+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434216+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434218+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434219+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434220+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434227+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434229+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434231+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434232+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434234+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434235+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:51) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434237+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434238+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434239+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434240+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434242+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434243+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434245+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434246+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434247+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434259+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434260+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434262+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434263+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434265+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434266+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434267+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434268+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434269+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434271+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434272+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434273+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434275+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434276+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434277+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434279+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434280+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434281+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434282+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434284+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434285+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434286+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434287+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434293+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434295+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434296+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434297+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434298+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434300+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434301+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434302+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434303+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434305+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434306+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434307+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434308+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434309+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434311+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434312+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434313+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434314+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434316+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434317+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434318+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434320+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434321+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434322+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434324+00:00 app[web.1]:    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:410) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434325+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434326+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434328+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:161) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434329+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 66 common frames omitted
2019-09-10T08:38:21.434331+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

And the error message:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-09-10T08:38:21.435+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "GENERAL"
}
```

When I'm debugging the request won't reach the microservice.

I have tried a lot of configuration but so far nothing works. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you disabling ribbon in zuul and also zuul from registering with eureka?

For zuul to route to the service it has to know the service name and its servers list, this  information zuul retrieves from eureka and ribbon uses it to route requests to the concerned service.

Enable both eureka and ribbon in zuul and it should probably start routing.

Comment: I enabled both eureka and ribbon in zuul and now I get "request timeout" error.

Comment: Can you update the question with the recent configuration?